# Javascript Sort SELECT Elements

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Is there an easy way to sort a list of HTML Select elements in Javascript? I would want it sorted by their names.  Each Select element has other fields like title and value.  Would I have to use arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use arrays:

```
var x = [];
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var length = select.options.length;
for(var i=length-1; i>=0; --i) {
   x.push(select.options[i]);
   select.removeChild(select.options[i]);
}
x.sort(function(o1,o2){
   if(o1.value > o2.value) {
      return 1;
   } else if(o1.value < o2.value) {
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
});
for(var i=0; i<length; ++i) {
   select.appendChild(x[i]);
}
```

Comment: I just added: "o1 = o1.toLowerCase();o2 = o2.toLowerCase();"  After the sort function so it sorts case insensitive. Worked perfectly, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reasons why you should use arrays:

- NodeLists are read-only (you can't apply array sorting to them)
- Array operations are super fast compared to DOM operations

So you basically need to convert the options into an array, then apply the `sort` function to it with the custom compare function. Finally you append back the elements in the correct order.

**Usage**

```
sortSelect("selection_id");
```

**Code [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ayodu3/)]**

```
(function(window){

// array functions are not working
// on nodeLists on IE, we need to
// to convert them to array
function toArray( obj ) {
  var i, arr = [];
  for ( i = obj.length; i--; ){
    arr[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return arr;
}

// custom compare function for sorting
// by the option's value
function sortByName( a, b ) {
  if ( a.value < b.value ) return -1;
  else if( a.value > b.value ) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

window.sortSelect = function(id) {

  // select the elements to be ordered
  var sel   = document.getElementById(id),
      items = sel.getElementsByTagName("option"),
      len   = items.length;

  // convert to array, to make sorting possible
  items = toArray( items );

  // do the item sorting by their value
  items = items.sort( sortByName );

  // append them back to the parent in order
  for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    sel.appendChild( items[i] );
  }
};

})(this);​
```

*Tested on: IE5.5+, FF2+, Chrome, Opera 9.6+*

Answer (score 0):

All buggy solutions..either because bad index or bad character handling..

Working solution. Add unicode where needed. True Bubble Sort

```
//tjcoder
function sortlist(cl){
    var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(var i=0;i<cl.length-1;i++){
        if(chars.indexOf(cl.options[i].text.substr(0,1).toLowerCase())>chars.indexOf(cl.options[i+1].text.substr(0,1).toLowerCase())){
            var tmp=cl.options[i].text;
            cl.options[i].text=cl.options[i+1].text;
            cl.options[i+1].text=tmp;
            i=-1;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I commented cause this is high on search indexes for search-options sorting, and all answer solutions are bugged.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Sort1()
{
var x1 = document.getElementById('s1');
var x2= new Array();
for(i=0;i<x1.length;i++)
{
 x2.push(x1[i].value);  
}

x2.sort();
x1.length=0;

for(i=0;i<x2.length;i++)
{
document.f1.s1[i]=new Option(x2[i],x2[i]);
}
}
</script>
<body>
<select id="s1" name="s1">
<option value="Sachin">Sachin</option>
<option value="Sehwag">Sehwag</option>
<option value="Zahir">Zahir</option>
<option value="Dhoni">Dhoni</option>

</select><br />
<input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="Sort1()" /><br />
</form>
</body>
```